# Memory dump in NetLogo, is it possible?

Tags: netlogo

I searched the NetLogo dictionary and didn't find it. Does anyone know if I can clear the NetLogo memory (memory dump)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can erase the current environment ( kill turtles, clear patch variables, Erase globals, etc with CLEAR-ALL. Is that what you mean?